# ¿Por qué no agrega el tiempo que se suma después de ofertar?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Esta función es de una subasta que tiene un límite de tiempo cuando le faltan 5 minutos para acabar, entonces un postor hace una oferta y se agregan otros 5 minutos a la subasta, hasta que no haya más ofertas la subasta termina. entonces no me agrega los 5 minutos después de ofertar  ni agrega los 5 minutos ala fecha final

**tiempo_regresivo.php**

```
<?php 
$secondsLimit=300;
$limitTime=$_POST["tiempo_limite"] ?? NULL;
if ($limitTime) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
    $currentDate = new \DateTime( "now");
    $endDate = new \DateTime($limitTime);
    # Calculamos el tiempo restante en segundos
    $secondsRemaining=$currentDate->getTimestamp()-$endDate->getTimestamp();
    $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
    $outPut = sprintf("Fecha actual:\t %s%s",$currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    $outPut .= sprintf("Fecha fin:\t %s%s",$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    if ($interval->format('%R') == '-' || $secondsRemaining===0) {
        $outPut .= "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
        ?>
        <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
      <?php
    } else {
        if ($secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit) {
            $outPut.=sprintf('<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar. Termina en %s segundos',$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));      
            if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {
                $minutesLimit=$secondsLimit/60;
                $endDate->add(new \DateInterval("PT{$minutesLimit}M"));
                $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNueva fecha fin: %s%s",PHP_EOL,$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%s<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: %s <br />",PHP_EOL,$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sSe realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos {$minutesLimit} minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado {$minutesLimit} minutos.",PHP_EOL);
            } else {
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo hubo nueva oferta",PHP_EOL);
            }                  
        } else {
            $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se cumple la condición $secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit",PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
} else {
    $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se posteó un valor para tiempo_limite",PHP_EOL);
}
echo $outPut;


?>
```

**Este código es el formulario que se agrega una oferta**

```
<?php
  if( ($_SESSION['rol'] == 'Comprador') && ($rst['Estado']=='Subasta') ){?>
      <form class = "form-inline" name ="ofertar" action="app/add_puja.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="idsubasta" value="<?php echo $idsubasta; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="envioart" value="<?php echo $rst['Nombre']; ?>"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="flimite" value="<?php echo $rst['Tiempo_Fin']; ?>">  
        <input type="hidden" name="vmin" value="<?php echo $rst['Valor_Minimo']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="incremento" value="<?php echo $rst['incremento']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="existe" value="<?php echo $rst9['existe']; ?>">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="oferta" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" min="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor'];?>"
             value="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor'];?>" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id= "ofertar" class="btn btn-warning" name="ofertar"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Ofertar</button>
      </form>
<?php }?>
```

**Este codigo es el add_puja.php donde se envia al formulario**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('classes/puja.php');
  

    if (isset($_POST["ofertar"])){
        $puja = new Puja();
        //Si el usuario quiere ofertar por un producto
      
            if($_POST["oferta"]< $_POST["vmin"]){
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor de oferta es menor al valor minimo.</center>";
            }
            else{               
                $puja->setIdsubasta($_POST["idsubasta"]);
                
                $rst = $puja->PujaMayor();
                $rst = $puja->PujasegundaMayor();
                $pujamayor = $rst['mayor'];
                $pujasegundamayor = $rst['segumayor'];
                $oferta = $_POST["oferta"];
                $envioart = $_POST["envioart"];
                $incremento = $_POST['incremento'];
    
                if($oferta <= $pujasegundamayor){
                    $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor debe ser mayor al de la puja actual.</center>";
                }
                else{
                    $puja->setUsername($_SESSION["username"]);       
                    $puja->setValor($oferta); //POST CAJA TEXTO oferta
                    $reg = $puja->Registrar();
                    if($reg){   
                        try{
                            $nombres = $_SESSION['apellidos']." ".$_SESSION['nombres']; 
                            $_SESSION['msgSuccess1'] = "<center>Puja Enviada.</center>";
                           
                            $asunto = "Hola ".$nombres." has realizado una puja exitosa en la subasta del artículo: ".$envioart." con un valor de: ".$oferta;
                            mail($_SESSION['correo'],"Puja Realizada", $asunto) ;
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Puja Exitosa, Correo no válido, no se notificó: '.$e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                    unset($reg); //libera el objeto PDOStatement           
                }
                unset($puja); //DESTRUCCION DEL OBJETO
            } 
              
        header('Location:' . getenv('HTTP_REFERER'));
    }
?>
```

**Este código es donde se agrega ala base de datos una oferta**

```
public function Registrar(){
            try{
                $sql = "INSERT INTO puja(Username, ID_Subasta, Valor, estado, Fecha)
                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, 1, NOW())";
                $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $result = $stm->execute(array($this->getUsername(), $this->getIdsubasta(), 
                                              $this->getValor()));
                $stm->closeCursor(); //Cierra cursor MySQL
                return $result;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Error al guardar: '.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

**Alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor**
estoy tratando de encontrar como hacerlo funcionar
Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** esta es la otra pregunta